# encoding images to video with ffpmeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, h.264

We are working on Android 3D Animation App.

We need to identify images, then save and encode the same to video using FFmpeg (Since Android API is not supporting). Once the video is generated, then audio is appended to the same.

We are facing 2 problems on this.

First is the memory leakage issue at the time of saving identified images for encoding. CPU of emulator is getting overloaded. Whether FFpmeg is called every time when an image is selected? How to resolve this issue?

Second (in case if we get through the first one) we are not able to encode the selected images, since this is generating green color video.  What could be reason for this?

Whether is there any tool other than FFmpeg for video encoding from images to H264?
Whether images version (Rastar or Vector) will impact this video encoding?
Whether Android OS version is considered?

Any valuable inputs on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I played also with that idea using ffmpeg on an android phone, but I would suggest to do that on a server which has much more power. On a server you don't need to think about the cpu load of a smartphone.

In general for improving your ffmpeg run you need to publish the ffmpeg calls. ffmpeg is quiet complex where the order of the parameters directly correlates with the efficience.

I don't know which container format you preferer but maybe a simple mjpeg codec could work for you. AFIK there a just the jpeg frames connected to each other which should be much simple then encoding a video to h264/x264 (ffmpeg uses the last one).

A combination of both may be to generate a mjpeg stream which will be converted on the server side to a h264 video which may be downloaded to the client. but that really depends on the length of the video if you don't want to waste the traffic of your customers.

Comment: Thanks for sending this. We will look into this.

Comment: @AndroidGeek If you like my answer please upvote it and if it is a solution for you accept it. :-)

Comment: Also, what about the reason for green color video generation. We are using NDK Approach in video encoding process of images with ffmpeg. Any response is appreciated.

Comment: About the green image I'm absolutly not sure. I saw that just with mpeg videos. I think that just means that the video stream is broken...